# How do I find the bbpress forum ID for a forum in a buddypress group?

Tags: buddypress, bbpress

I am trying to modify this code https://www.daggerhart.com/bbpress-recent-replies-shortcode/ but I have specific questions and cannot find the answer. This code above generates a shortcode like [bbpress_recent_replies_by_topic show=10 forum=123]

I have a buddypress site with groups, and each group has its own bbpress forum. I want to list the recent replies for the **forum assigned to that group** (only) when a user visits the group page. So basically I want to assign the forum ID based on whichever group the user is in and is seeing the widget in.

This is the function in the code above:

```
function custom_bbpress_recent_replies_by_topic($atts){
    $short_array = shortcode_atts(array('show' => 5, 'forum' => false, 'include_empty_topics' => false), $atts);
    extract($short_array);
```

Instead of `'forum' => false`, I want it to point to `'forum' => _bbp_forum_id` or something like that. However, that doesn't work because I'm at the group home page so there is no forum there yet until you click "forums" in the group menu. I don't know how database links the budddypress group to the bbpress forum id.

Some questions:
1) How do I find out the forum id for the group’s assigned forum? Is it _bbp_forum_id ?
2) How do I then assign that forum ID to to be the default forum ID for the widget in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forum id for a group is stored in the `{yourprefix}_bp_groups_groupsmeta table` where `group_id` is the group id and the key is `forum_id` and the value is a serialized array.

Instead of a shortcode, it may be easier to add a function call in a bp groups template. 
Something like: `echo gauray_recent_replies( bp_get_group_id() );`

```
function gauray_recent_replies( $group_id ) {
   $forum_id = bbp_get_group_forum_ids( $group_id );
   // collect and return replies
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! 
I ended up using `bbp_get_group_forum_ids( $group_id )[0]` to get the id of the first (main) forum attached, and pointed ` 'forum' => bbp_get_group_forum_ids( $group_id )[0] `